# "First time" test

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, tips, c

What is the shortest C expression that is defined to evaluated to false the first time and true for every time after that:

Reference implementation:

```
bool b = false;  // you get this for free.

(b ? true : b = true, false)  // only this line is measured.
```

Comment: Since the task description in fact states that it should return `true` for **every** time after the initial `false`, I'd say that solutions that work only a limited time (even if it's 500+ years) don't count as correct solutions.

Answer (score 11):

#### 3 chars:

As Keith Randall suggested in a comment, if we can use floats or doubles, this should do the trick:

```
float b = 0;  // free

b++
```

Eventually, as `b` is incremented repeatedly, two things may happen: either the addition overflows (and thus evaluates to `HUGE_VAL`, which may be infinite or a large positive value) or, more likely, the roundoff step size simply grows larger than one, turning the increment into a no-op.  In either case, the expression should continue to evaluate as true.

Comment: That will happen at ~`1/ε`  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: I think that is valid and I don't think anything smaller is going to work (there are no mutating single char unary operators). OTOH coercion a floating point to bool offends my sensibilities (as well as FP-ops being slower than int-ops).

Comment: To be precise, `b` stops growing at 16777216.0 (=2^24), as there are only 23 bits of mantissa in a `float`.

Comment: BTW: I'm not sure but ++ on a bool might work as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3450554/1343

Answer (score 10):

**6 characters**

```
int i = 0; //free
i||i++
```

OTOH: I like Peter Taylor's solution as it has no branch so it may be faster (depending on compiler details).

p.s. I came up with that after posting the question (honest!).

Comment: After the first time, the left side of the `||` will be true and short-circuit evaluation will prevent the right side from getting evaluated so nothing gets updated.

Comment: Argh, indeed. I take that back :)

Answer (score 8):

With:

```
long long b = 0;
```

then three characters are enough for many applications:

```
b++
```

Evaluates false first and true for a long time thereafter ;-)

Comment: I'd say it'll be true for a long, long time.

Comment: It evaluates true only 18446744073709551614 times, not forever :-/

Comment: Use a `double` and it will be true forever!

Comment: And unless you make that unsigned, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: 18446744073709551614 times.  Assuming we could perform this operation 1 billion times per second, it would take about 585 years.

Comment: -1: Does not follow specs `true for every time after that`.

Comment: I flagged it for deletion.

Answer (score 7):

**7 characters**

As Peter Taylor suggested, still `int a = 2;`

```
!(a/=2)
```

**8 characters (old)**

Start with `int a = 2;`

```
!(a>>=1)
```

Another version of this: `int b = 0x40000000;`

```
!(b<<=1)
```

Comment: The first one is portable. The second isn't. But doesn't `!(a/=2)` work?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yeah, you're right. Thinking too complicated ...

Comment: The left shift works and is defined if you go with `unsigned int`s and use `0xD...` which I think you can get in a portable way via `~((~0u)>>2)`.

Comment: @BCS thanks for the info, but I'll just leave it at that because the other two versions are shorter anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### 9 chars:

```
b=0;//free
(b&(b=1))
```

at least if it's valid c (not undefined behavior)

### 12 chars

```
(b?b:!(b=1))
```

this is valid c

Answer (score 1):

#### <s>11</s> 10 chars

I can't beat the three char approach, but make it different:

```
int b = 0;  // free

b?b:0*(b=1) // 11 characters
b||0*(b=1)  // one character less thanks to breadbox
```

Comment: That wound count as 11 and doesn't work as it is two different expressions.

Comment: @BCS I thought the first initialization was for free (so, the chars do not count), and the second one is an expression to be evaluated. I fail to see why wouldn't it work.

Comment: I was summing you were considering the expression in the first line to be the "gives false" and the other to be the "gives true". ---- The expression will evaluate to 1 (i.e. true) every time, including the first. The spec is that the expression is true the first time and false there after.

Comment: @BCS Got it! Will update now to reflect your correction and will think a little bit about it. I'll see if I can give it a twist. Thanks!

Comment: `b?b=1:0*(b=1)` actually works.

Comment: @walpen Thanks! I had completely forgotten about this answer. I've updated based on your comment, reducing out the first b=1 to b, as it would be already 1 in that case, right? (Or is there something else I am overseeing?)

Comment: You don't need the ternary operator; `b||0*(b=1)` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
int b=1; // for free
!b|(b=0)
```

bit-wise or works as well since in first trial `0|0` yields 0 and in other trials `!0|0` yields `!0` which is guaranteed to be true. It is also ANSI-compliant, I've tried the following code with GCC 4.6.1 with `-ansi` flag:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main () {
  int b=1, i=0;
  for (;i<5;++i)
    printf ("%d",!b|(b=0));
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior. The compiler could evaluate `b=0` first and `!b` later, making it true the first time.

Answer (score 1):

### APL (5 or 6)

If I'm only allowed to initialize the variable to 0, it's 6 characters:

```
A←0    ⍝ free
⊃A←⍴⍴A
```

How it works: `⍴A` is the size of A (which is the empty list the first time around, because `0` is a scalar), so `⍴⍴A` is the size of the size of A (which is `[0]` the first time, because a one-dimensional empty list has zero values in one dimension). This is then assigned to A (`A←`) and the first element is returned (`⊃`).

1. `A` is `0`, `⍴A` is `[]`, then `A` is set to `⍴⍴A` which is `[0]`, and the first element is returned (`0`).
2. `A` is `[0]`, `⍴A` is `[1]`, then `A` is set to `⍴⍴A` which is `[1]`, and the first element is returned (`1`).
3. `A` is `[1]`, so `⍴A` remains `[1]`, so `A` is set to `⍴⍴A` which remains `[1]` and it returns `1`.

If I'm allowed to initialise the variable to anything I want, I can set it to the empty list and drop one of the `⍴`s to make it 5 characters:

```
A←⍬    ⍝ free, set to empty list
⊃A←⍴A
```

Answer (score 0):

**9 chars**

```
b=1; //free
!b||(b=0)
```

*edited: no longer undefined behavior*

Comment: that very similar to `a=a++` which is undefined

Comment: now defined, +3 chars :(

Answer (score 0):

```
bool b = false; // for free?
b = b?b:!b;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
bool b = false;

!b+b++
```

Comment: I think that is undefined behavior (and it will overflow and reset)

Comment: Why do you think so? What exactly is undefined? plusplusing a boolean? Or the priority of post-increment operation?

Comment: 1) The value depends on order of evaluation which is undefined behavior. 2) Either that will eventually overflow (and both hit undefined behavior as well as return false) or the 3 char solution (b++) works with bool as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3450554/1343

Comment: The answer in the link you provided quotes C++03 standard. Does this standard apply to C99 as well?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that it is undefined in C as well.

Answer (score -3):

## 1 Character

Since you didn't specify which compiler and/or which command line options are to be used, here's my 1 character solution:

```c
bool b = false;

X
```

Compile with

```sh
gcc -DX='(b ? true : b = true, false)'
```

Comment: As a general rule, codegolf counts special command-line options towards the score. So this would be 41+ characters.